# JavaScriptで GUID / UUID（ランダムな文字列）を生成するには

Tags: javascript, jquery

Windows系の開発でよく出てくるGUIDのようなランダムな文字列を生成したいです。

一定の長さ以上のランダムな文字列を生成するだけなので自作できると思いますが、jQueryなどの普及しているライブラリで提供されている関数、または標準的な生成方法があれば、そちらに倣いたいと思います。

Comment: [本家](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript)に合わせてタイトルを修正しました

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UUIDの生成には、乱数を使う場合の仕様 [RFC4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) がありますので、できればそれに従うようにしましょう。

コードなら、こんな感じ。 ([gistより引用](https://gist.github.com/jcxplorer/823878))

```
function uuid() {
  var uuid = "", i, random;
  for (i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    random = Math.random() * 16 | 0;

    if (i == 8 || i == 12 || i == 16 || i == 20) {
      uuid += "-"
    }
    uuid += (i == 12 ? 4 : (i == 16 ? (random & 3 | 8) : random)).toString(16);
  }
  return uuid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

本家に同様の質問がありました。

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105034/create-guid-uuid-in-javascript

```
    var guid = (function() {
      function s4() {
        return Math.floor((1 + Math.random()) * 0x10000)
                   .toString(16)
                   .substring(1);
      }
      return function() {
        return s4() + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' + s4() + '-' +
               s4() + '-' + s4() + s4() + s4();
      };
    })();
```

[追記]えいやっで上からとってきたコードが間違い（IDの仕様的に）との指摘から、取り消し線をいれました。

Comment: ありがとうございます。UUIDという言い方もあるんですね。

Comment: 本回答のリンク先の内容を確認したところ、引用されたコードは間違ったもので、2番目にある1000vote以上ある方がより正しいものとなっているようです。

Comment: ぬ、了解です。取り消し線いれておきます

Comment: 承認マークがついたままですし、分かりづらいですよね ^^;  訂正ありがとうございます。